# How to model a one-to-many?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've got two entities, Item and City. How can I model like a one-to-many relation so that it represents that an item can "have" many cities? I'd like to do it with ReferenceProperty but it seems that it would be a list and there is no property for lists of keys AFAIK. Can you tell me how I should model in order to represent the relation?

When creating new objects it is possible to make something like a one-to-many if you are creating new objects with referenceproperty that is a collection:

```
class ItemLocation(db.Model):   
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty(Item,
            collection_name='matched_cities', verbose_name='Cities')
```

But this is not exactly what I want. I want a convenient modelling where I can iterate over the cities for a given item i.e.

`{% for city in item.matched_cities %}`

Can you tell me how I should do this?

Thank you

Comment: This does sound like a many-to-many relationship to me, since you said that a item can have several cities, but I guess a city can have many items, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely have a list of keys. Add this to your Item model:

```
cities = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

Then, you can retrieve those cities from the datastore with

```
itemsCities = ItemLocation.get(item.cities)
```